# How to partition strings from a list in python

Tags: python, list

What would be the best way to partition text strings from a list in python example:

```
["AVE FCO MADERO", "AVE FRANCISCO I MADERO"]

str = "AVE FCO MADERO MZA 23 LT 43"
str = "AVE FRANCISCO I MADERO # 455 MZA 3 INT 4"
```

Wanting to have variable partitioning

```
v1 = "AVE FCO MADERO"
v2 = "MZA 23 LT 43"

v1 = "AVE FRANCISCO I MADERO"
v2 = "# 455 MZA 3 INT 4"
```

Comment: slicing with the length of the prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and slices.

```
def split(ss , prefixes):
    for prefix in prefixes:
        if ss.find(prefix)==0:
            return (ss[:len(prefix)],ss[len(prefix):])
    return "",""
```

---

```
>>> s1,s2 = split("AVE FCO MADERO MZA 23 LT 43", prefixes)
('AVE FCO MADERO', ' MZA 23 LT 43')
>>> s1,s2 = split("AVE FRANCISCO I MADERO # 455 MZA 3 INT 4", prefixes)
('AVE FRANCISCO I MADERO', ' # 455 MZA 3 INT 4')
```